# Is there a PHP function that only adds slashes to double quotes NOT single quotes

Tags: php, json

I am generating JSON with PHP.

I have been using

```
$string = 'This string has "double quotes"';

echo addslashes($string);
```

outputs: `This string has \" double quotes\"`

Perfectly valid JSON

**Unfortunately addslashes also escapes single quotes with catastrophic results for valid JSON**

```
$string = "This string has 'single quotes'";

echo addslashes($string);
```

outputs: `This string has \'single quotes\'`

In short, is there a way to only escape double quotes?

Comment: Use: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Although you should use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode) if it’s available to you, you could also use [`addcslashes`](http://php.net/addcslashes) to add `\` only to certain characters like:

```
addcslashes($str, '"\\/')
```

You could also use a regular expression based replacement:

```
function json_string_encode($str) {
    $callback = function($match) {
        if ($match[0] === '\\') {
            return $match[0];
        } else {
            $printable = array('"' => '"', '\\' => '\\', "\b" => 'b', "\f" => 'f', "\n" => 'n', "\r" => 'r', "\t" => 't');
            return isset($printable[$match[0]])
                   ? '\\'.$printable[$match[0]]
                   : '\\u'.strtoupper(current(unpack('H*', mb_convert_encoding($match[0], 'UCS-2BE', 'UTF-8'))));
        }
    };
    return '"' . preg_replace_callback('/\\.|[^\x{20}-\x{21}\x{23}-\x{5B}\x{5D}-\x{10FFFF}/u', $callback, $str) . '"';
}
```

Answer (score 21):

> Is there a PHP function that only adds slashes to double quotes NOT single quotes

There is no function like [`addslashes()`](http://php.net/addslashes) that only adds a slash to double quotes.

However you can make use of [`addcslashes()`](http://php.net/addcslashes) to only add slashes to specific characters, e.g. **only** to double quotes:

```
addcslashes($string, '"');
```

That does exactly as described. If you want to have it compatible with [`stripcslashes()`](http://php.net/stripcslashes) however, you need to add the slash itself to the list of chars:

```
addcslashes($string, '"\\');
```

That should do the job you've been asking for. I have no idea if that is compatible with json encoding.

Answer (score 5):

If you are generating JSON, why not just use the [**`json_encode()`**](https://www.php.net/json_encode) function ?

Comment: If the persone didn't know about this function and it solves his problem it is in the scope of the question.

Comment: @koen Exactly. Plus he also asked "In short, is there a way to only escape double quotes?"

Comment: Thanks. Yes unfortunately json_encode was not applicable to this situation.

Comment: json_encode() will fail for certain character combinations, like "\'". You will get a parse error. You can use addcslashes before to escape sequences like that.

Answer (score 2):

```
function json_string_encode( $str ) {
   $from = array('"');    // Array of values to replace
   $to = array('\\"');    // Array of values to replace with

   // Replace the string passed
   return str_replace( $from, $to, $str );
}
```

To use the function you simply need to use

```
$text = json_string_encode($text);
```

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer! While a code snippet could answer the question it's still great to add some addition information around, like explain, etc ..