# Block of text with both types of quotes as a string

Tags: php, string, escaping, quotes, double-quotes

I'm working with a site that's based on some custom templating system. Let's say that in a template I can use tag **[custom_text]** which will output the entire block of html like this, defined through the CMS's rich text editor:

```
<b>Lorem ipsum dolor</b> sit amet, "consectetur adipisicing elit"<br /><br />
<b>sed doeiusmod</b> tempor incididunt ut's labore et dolore magna's aliqua.
```

Please note that it contains both types of quotes in it. I am not able to preprocess anything that comes out of the templating system other than actually outputting it to the page, as the CMS with templating system is encoded.

Now I actually need to manipulate that block, for instance to remove all the line breaks from the code. I can use php on the page, but I cannot define a string that would contain that block of code. If I do it either way:

```
$string = "[custom_text]";
$string = '[custom_text]';
```

the quotes in the block will come in the way, ending the string prematurely. Is there any obvious way to handle this issue?

Comment: `addslashes()` is not helping?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611468/is-there-a-php-function-that-only-adds-slashes-to-double-quotes-not-single-quote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know why I haven't thought of this before, but I can simply use the heredoc syntax.

```
$string = <<<EOT
[custom_text]
EOT;
```

will solve the case.

Answer (score 0):

Try This One

```
<?php
$string = "This string has 'single quotes'";
echo addcslashes($string, '"\\');
?>
```

The Output Will Be Like Below

```
This string has 'single quotes'
```

This Answer From This Link

[Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611468/is-there-a-php-function-that-only-adds-slashes-to-double-quotes-not-single-quote)

Comment: This would have worked, however the block of text that I need to put in the string already has BOTH types of quotes in it and I am not able to pre-process it in any way prior to outputting it. If I were to use single quotes to define the string, it would end up like this:

    $string = '<b>Lorem ipsum dolor</b> sit amet, "consectetur adipisicing elit"<br /><br /><b>sed doeiusmod</b> tempor incididunt ut's labore et dolore magna's aliqua.';

As you can see, the apostrophe in the block of text effectively closes the string definition's single quote.

Comment: can i know that from where did u get the string